# Utilize console logging in native javascript promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, es6-promise

I have a native javascript promise chain that looks a little like this:

```
function chain() {
  promiseFunction1().then(function(data) {

    console.log("some message");
    return promiseFunction2();

  }).then(function(data) {

    console.log("some message");
    return promiseFunction3();

  }).then(function(data) {

    console.log("some message");
    return promiseFunction4();

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error.stack);
  });

}
```

the promise functions would look a little like this:

```
function promiseFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
     someCallbackfunction(arg, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        console.log("some message");
        return resolve(data);
     });
  });
}
```

My code seems to resolve fine from what I can tell (no errors and I can tell from terminal feedback that the operations I needed started running) but no matter what I seem to try I cannot for the life of me seem to get any form of console logging.

1) Why are these statements not printing like I expect them to?

2) How can I go about getting back my verbose output?

Comment: Are you getting the `some message` from inside the callback function? If not, then `someCallbackFunction` is to blame.

Comment: Try `console.error("Error", error)`. It might be that `error.stack` is undefined on whatever the callback-based function rejects with, and you're not getting any logs because of that.

Comment: @Bergi I tried using  `console.error("Error", error)` without success. Also the some message is not called, inside the promise functions or the someCallback. I do know for a fact that the first two some promise functions resolve correctly since I can see the messages for their operations appearing in `journalctl`

Comment: I found that indeed there seems to be some problem with the 3rd promise function, not sure if it is an error or if the promise never resolves since it is hard to tell without output.

Comment: How did you resolve it? https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @Andreas, One of my functions had an internal callback that went to another library that never returned. As a result the chain never completed and I got no output. Fixing the method helped. If you want I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @MSB My own issue actually turned out to be something similar. Maybe would be nice to add as an answer, seems like something easily overlooked!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that in the end the problem was external.
Somewhere in my promise chain I called an external library with a callback function but the library never responded causing my chain to wait forever.

If you experience something similar I encourage you to double check all of the functions in the chain for a similar occurrence.

A quick way to debug this could be to place a timeout in each promise function in the chain that resolves it after x amount of time, that way you can at least get your logging results without having to stumble in the dark forever.